# Combine date and time from two separate columns in a csvreader generator object

Tags: python, generator, python-datetime, csvreader

I have a CSV file like this:

```
2021-08-09 15:50:44      38962 part-00000-6baa0883-5212-49f7-9ba2-63a352211fdd-c000.snappy.parquet
2021-08-09 16:50:44      38962 part-00000-6baa0883-5212-49f7-9ba2-63a352211fdd-c000.snappy.parquet
```

I'd like to extract all the timestamps into one list so that I can perform the evaluation function below (ie evaluating if `check_timestamps_updated` is true).

Problem is also taking the date into account, not just the time. What's the most efficient way of combining the two separate columns (date and time) from the `csvreader object` so that it can be compared with `control_time`?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

control_time = str(str(dt.now()))
reader = csv.reader(results, delimiter=" ")
        time_column = list(zip(*reader))[1]
        check_timestamps_updated = all(i >= control_time for i in time_column)
```

Comment: If you just want to compare the time then probably want to set the control time as `control_time = str(dt.now().time())` so your only taking the time part from dt not the date

Comment: That's the thing - I had that before and it worked. Then it gave a false positive because the date also matters. Hence, I need to include the date as well...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you want to do can be implemented as below,

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

check_timestamps_updated = True
control_time = dt.now().timestamp()
with open('example.csv', newline='\n') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for line in reader:
        date = dt.strptime(f'{line[0]} {line[1]}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
        if date >= control_time:
            check_timestamps_updated = False
print(check_timestamps_updated)
```

You asked the most efficient way to merge two columns but I think it depends on what you are mentioning as efficiency. If the csv file is too big and if there is a chance to have a memory problem what I implemented above can work without an issue. But if you are mentioning time this is still a good one.

Comment: But I'd like it to compare both date and time, not just time.

Comment: @PianoTiger I updated the `time` to `timestamp` I think it is the answer what you are asking